# Azure storage avoid uploading file if name already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to upload a file to azure storage. I have it working using the package `multer-azure` however if I upload a file with the same name of one already stored in the storage, the first one will get replaced.

From docs it seems like I need to add a `ETagMatch` but I am not sure where this should go.

https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/global.html#AccessConditions

My code:

```
      var upload = multer({
        storage: multerAzure({
            account: STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, //The name of the Azure storage account
            key: ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY, //A key listed under Access keys in the storage account pane
            container: 'demo',  //Any cntainer name, it will be created if it doesn't exist
            blobPathResolver:  (_req, file, callback) => {
                let path;
                if(_req.body.pathToFile) {
                    path = `${organization}/${_req.body.pathToFile}/${file.originalname}`
                } else {
                    path = `${organization}/${file.originalname}`;
                }
                // var blobPath = yourMagicLogic(req, file); //Calculate blobPath in your own way.
                callback(null, path);
            }
        })
    }).single('file')

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        } else if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        }
        return res.status(200).send(req.file)
    })
```

Comment: How about doing it the proper way and check if the file exist before allowing upload?

Comment: Also doing this from client side (it looks like thats what you are doing) will expose your storage key which means that anyone can take it and copy/delete everything.

Comment: @DanielBjörk I actually havent seen that file exist check in the API? and no this is not browser code its Node (multer doesnt even exist in the client..0

Comment: There is many way eg. You could use the Get Blob Properties to see if it exists. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api

Comment: Checking if a blob exists in the client and then uploading it if it doesn't may not cut it, depending on the scenarrio. In a service where multiple nodes may be running this code, you will have a race condition between checking and uploading which can cause you to overwrite an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

If the blob already exists on the service, it will be overwritten. You can simply use [`doesBlobExist`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#doesBlobExist__anchor) method of the SDK to check if a blob exists in a path in NodeJS. If not exist, you could upload a file to Azure storage.

```
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(storageAccount, accessKey);
blobService.doesBlobExist('azureblob', 'xxx/a.json', function(error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    if (result.exists) {
      console.log('Blob exists...');
    } else {
      console.log('Blob does not exist...');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This results in a race condition - if some other service uploads the blob between checking if it exists and uploading it, you will overwrite.

Comment: Is a blob lease the only way to prevent a racing condition? is there some reference implementation available?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on the original intuition of @mmxx11.  From the link provided one can see the statement about EtagNonMatch:
"If the ETag for the blob does not match the specified ETag.
Specify the wildcard character (*) to perform the operation only if the resource does not exist, and fail the operation if it does exist."

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/storage-blob/blobrequestconditions?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobrequestconditions-ifnonematch one can specify a string.

Thus, combining those details, one specifies the tag as '*' to get the desired effect.

I'm using @azure/storage-blob@12.17.0 and so in summary, do this:

```
const containerClient = await blobClient.getContainerClient("containername");
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient("blobname");

var result = await blobClient.uploadData(blob, { conditions: { ifNoneMatch: '*'} });
```

Cheers!